# Assembly MIPS - Shift of an address

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, mips, mips32, machine-code

I'm making some exercises on assembly MIPS(32 bit) and I don't really understand how the left shift by 2 works.
I'll add a couple of examples just to explain it better.

- Instruction is *0x91050014*
  I have to take the last 16 bits and then extend them to 32 bits.
  So I take *0014* and since the MSB is a zero it means that it's a positive number so I extend it to 32 bits like follows: *0x00000014*
  After that I have to apply a shift to the left by 2, so ( I use [] for deleting and {} for adding): 
   *[00]00 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0100{00}*
  Which I can conclude is *0x00000050*

---

I've got problems once the last 16 bytes aren't positive, like in this example:

- Instruction is *0x10A6FFEC*
  I take *FFEC* and since the MSB is an F it means that it's a negative number so I extend it to 32 bits like follows: *0xFFFFFFEC*
  Now I find myself with this: *1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110 1100*
  And I don't understand how to apply the shift.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Exactly the same way. By the way they're 16 bits, not bytes.

Comment: @harold Corrected, sorry. So I just delete the first couple of 11 and add 00 as LSB and I should get _0xFFFFFFB0_, correct?

Comment: @harold Perfect. If it's not too much to ask I'd have one last thing, as the very last step I have to calculate the sum with PC, it's _0x0000080C_ + _0xFFFFFFB0_. The result should be _0x1000007BC_ but since I have to stick with 32 bits is it correct to say just _0x000007BC_ ?

Comment: Yes, and you see it works out with the interpretation of 0xFFFFFFB0 being negative

Comment: @harold Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

the same way

1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110 1100

will be

[11]11 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110 1100{00}

so it's

1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1011 0000

0xffffffb0